# Tic-Tac-Toe in C++11

Tags: c++, game, c++11, tic-tac-toe

I have found Tic-Tac-Toe source code: [Tic Tac Toe in C++](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/47609/tic-tac-toe-in-c)

I have rewritten the source code in C++11 as shown below. How can I minimize hardcoding in the game logic?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>

class TicTacToe
{
public:
    bool isFull() const;
    void draw() const;
    void turn(char player);
    bool check(char player) const;

private:
    bool fill(char player, int position);

private:
    static const std::size_t mDim = 3;
    std::array<char, mDim * mDim> grid
    { 
        {   
            '-', '-', '-',
            '-', '-', '-',
            '-', '-', '-' 
        } 
    };
};

template<std::size_t dim>
struct column : public std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    column(int i) : colNum(i){}
    bool operator() (int number) { return (number % dim == colNum); }
    int colNum;
};

bool TicTacToe::fill(char player, int position)
{
    if (grid[position] != '-')
        return false;
    grid[position] = player;
    return true;
}

bool TicTacToe::isFull() const
{
    return 0 == std::count_if(grid.begin(), grid.end(),
        [](const char& i)
    {
        return '-';
    });
}

bool TicTacToe::check(char player) const
{
    column<mDim>::argument_type input;

    // check for row or column wins
    bool row1 = true, row2 = true, row3 = true,
        col1 = true, col2 = true, col3 = true,
        diag1 = true, diag2 = true;
    int j = 0;

    // columns
    std::for_each(grid.begin(), grid.end(), 
        [&](char i)
    {
        int x = j++;

        if (column<mDim>(0)(input = x)) 
            col1 &= i == player;

        if (column<mDim>(1)(input = x)) 
            col2 &= i == player;

        if (column<mDim>(2)( input = x)) 
            col3 &= i == player;
    });

    // diagonals
    j = 0;
    for (const auto& i : grid)
    {
        int x = j++;
        if (x == 0 || x == 4 || x == 8)
            diag1 &= i == player;
        if (x == 2 || x == 4 || x == 6)
            diag2 &= i == player;
    }

    if (col1 || col2 || col3 || diag1 || diag2)
        return true;

    // rows
    return std::search_n(grid.begin(), grid.end(), 3, player) != grid.end();
}

void TicTacToe::draw() const
{
    //Creating a onscreen grid
    std::cout << ' ';
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i <= mDim; ++i)
        std::cout << "  " << i;

    int j = 0;
    char A = 'A';
    column<mDim>::argument_type input;

    for (auto& i : grid)
    {
        int x = j++;
        if (column<mDim>(0)(input = x ))
            std::cout << "\n " << A++;

        std::cout << ' ' << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

void TicTacToe::turn(char player)
{
    char row = 0;
    char column = 0;
    std::size_t position = 0;
    bool applied = false;

    std::cout << "\n" << player << ": Please play. \n";

    while (!applied) 
    {
        std::cout << "Row(1,2,3,...): ";
        std::cin >> row;
        std::cout << player << ": Column(A,B,C,...): ";
        std::cin >> column;

        position = mDim * (std::toupper(column) - 'A') + (row - '1');

        if (position < grid.size()) 
        {
            applied = fill(player, position);

            if (!applied)
                std::cout << "Already Used. Try Again. \n";
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid position.  Try again.\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

class Game
{
public:
    Game();
    void run();

private:
    TicTacToe ttt;
    std::array<char, 2> players{ { 'X', 'O' } };
    int player = 0;

    std::function<void()>       display = std::bind(&TicTacToe::draw, &ttt);
    std::function<void(char)>   turn    = std::bind(&TicTacToe::turn, &ttt, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<bool(char)>   win     = std::bind(&TicTacToe::check, &ttt, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<bool()>       full    = std::bind(&TicTacToe::isFull, &ttt);
};

Game::Game()
    :ttt()
{

}

void Game::run()
{
    while (!win(players[player]) && !full())
    {
        player ^= 1;
        display();
        turn(players[player]);
    }

    display();

    if (win) 
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << players[player] << " is the Winner!\n";
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "\nTie game!\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.run();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some things that may allow you to improve your code:

### Eliminate unused variables

In the `check` routine, the variables `row1`, `row2` and `row3` are initialized but unused.  It would be best to eliminate them.

### Fix `check` code

The code does not correctly evaluate when a player has won.  For example, if I redirect this file to the game:

```
2
B
1
A
2
A
2
C
1
C
3
A
3
B
```

The result is this:

```
   1  2  3
 A X  O  X 
 B -  O  O 
 C O  X  - 


O is the Winner!
```

Clearly that's not right.

I'd write it like this:

```
bool TicTacToe::check(char player) const
{
    // check for row or column wins
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < mDim; ++i){
        bool rowwin = true;
        bool colwin = true;
        for (unsigned j=0; j < mDim; ++j) {
            rowwin &= grid[i*mDim+j] == player;
            colwin &= grid[j*mDim+i] == player;
        }
        if (colwin || rowwin) 
            return true;
    }
    // check for diagonal wins
    bool diagwin = true;
    for (unsigned i=0; i < mDim; ++i) 
        diagwin &= grid[i*mDim+i] == player;
    if (diagwin) 
        return true;
    diagwin = true;
    for (unsigned i=0; i < mDim; ++i) 
        diagwin &= grid[i*mDim+(mDim-i-1)] == player;
    return diagwin; 
}
```

### Fix `Game::run`

The code currently includes the following code in `Game::run()`:

```
if (win)
{
    std::cout << "\n" << players[player] << " is the Winner!\n";
}
```

However, that's an error because `win` is `std::function<bool(char)>` and this is not an invocation of that function.  In fact, what it's doing is checking to see if the address of the function is `nullptr`.  It never is, so this code will always claim there's a winner, even if the game was actually a tie. Either invoke the function again as `win(players[player])` or, better, save the result from the previous invocation a few lines above and test that.

### Avoid unnecessary obfuscation

The code for `Game::run` uses `std::bind` to essentially redefine four functions of the `TicTacToe` class.  It would be much simpler to simply call those functions directly.  For example, instead of writing `!full()` you could simply call `!ttt.isFull()`.

### Eliminate `column`

The `column` function makes the code more complex rather than less and is created and destroyed many many times during the course of a regular game.  (On a sample run with a tie game here, 90 `column` objects were created and destroyed.)

For example, the code for `TicTacToe::draw()` contains this code:

```
column<mDim>::argument_type input;

for (auto& i : grid)
{
    int x = j++;
    if (column<mDim>(0)(input = x ))
        std::cout << "\n " << A++;

    std::cout << ' ' << i << ' ';
}
```

It can be rewritten in much simpler form without `column`:

```
for (auto& i : grid)
{
    if (j++ % mDim == 0)
        std::cout << "\n " << A++;
    std::cout << ' ' << i << ' ';
}
```

### Consider function names carefully

The function named `isFull()` is well-named, but others are not.  For instance, the `fill` function would probably make more sense named `apply` or `applyMove`.  The word `fill` implies that the entire array is filled, which is not actually the purpose for this function.

### Use a constructor for `TicTacToe`

Most of the code carefuly uses `mDim` as a potentially changeable parameter denoting the dimension of the board.  However, the `grid` member is statically initialized with a hand-created array of `-` characters.  Better would be to simply define `grid` like this:

```
std::array<char, mDim * mDim> grid;
```

and then create a constructor:

```
TicTacToe() { grid.fill('-'); }
```

### Avoid "magic numbers"

A few places within the code use `'-'` to signify an empty square.  However, this should instead be a `static const` member of the `TicTacToe` class instead.

### Simplify `isFull()`

Rather than check each square in the grid each turn, it would probably be simpler just to maintain a number of empty squares.

### Consider revising the class responsibilities

Right now, the `Game` class keeps track of the turns, does some of the I/O and contains a `TicTacToe` object.  Better might be to make it responsible for all of the I/O and have `TicTacToe` incorporate only the logic of the game.  This is a step toward what is called the [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern.  The use is that if, at some future point, you wished to convert this game into, say, a graphical program with a touch-screen interface, you would only have to rework `Game` and not the `TicTacToe` class.

### Thoroughly validate user input

Right now, the code will allow the user to input a position of (0,B) which it interprets as (3,A) and (0,D) as (3,C). Even stranger input, such as (/,B) is also accepted.  It would be better to make sure that what the user inputs is actually valid.  Most of the logic is already there -- it just needs some improvement.

Comment: unfortunately, you have logic error in check funtion. try this:1a1b2a2b3b3a

Comment: @MORTAL: that sequence works just fine here.  What do you see when you try it?

Comment: it gave me: O is the Winner!. here my code in gists:https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8090aad86a7a4861f168

Answer (score 3):

Instead of defining the winning conditions by using a bunch of for-loops in your code, you can define the winning conditions by using an actual array for them.

Let's say that each win condition is an integer array. The array `[ 0, 4, 8 ]` is then the win-condition representing the top-left to bottom-right diagonal.

So what you can use is an array of these win conditions.

Then, when checking for a winner, loop through the win conditions and check if there is one win condition that rules them all (i.e., if a player has played on all the positions in the win condition).

To setup the win conditions, I would recommend using a method similar to my `loopAdd` method. Also take a look at my `TTWinCondition` class in my [Tic-Tac-Toe Ultimate implementation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/45086/recursive-and-flexible-approach-to-tic-tac-toe)

Answer (score 3):

I just have some minor points to address, though I haven't looked at the entire code.

- You can just combine the `private` sections in `TicTacToe`.  It doesn't really matter to separate member variables and functions.  You can still add whitespace between them.
- You don't need a blank constructor in C++11:

  > ```
  > Game::Game()
  >     :ttt()
  > {
  >
  > }
  > ```

  If you need to provide one, then you can use a [`default` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor) instead:

  ```
  Game() = default;
  ```

  This would just go in the class declaration.
- Consider adding an additional function for determining the winner so that `run()` doesn't have to handle this other task.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the code:

```
 bool TicTacToe::isFull() const
{
    return 0 == std::count_if(grid.begin(), grid.end(),
        [](const char& i)
    {
       // return '-';  <-- error here
    });
}
```

The return value was missing a parameter. The correct one is:

```
 bool TicTacToe::isFull() const
{
    return 0 == std::count_if(grid.begin(), grid.end(),
        [](const char& i)
    {
        return i == '-'; 
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before explain recent change, allow me to explain what was bothering me with my previous code.

Problems in my original source code was the game logic where I have hard-coding game-logic in the function `check()` . As it seems there are 3 `for`-loop to compute the logic condition checking for both the player as input, and grid array and punch of `bool` variables.

The first `for`-loop is to check any matching between player and columns and assign it `col1`, `col2`, `col3` via bitwise AND operator:

```
// columns
std::for_each(grid.begin(), grid.end(), 
    [&](char i)
{
    int x = j++;

    if (column<mDim>(0)(input = x)) 
        col1 &= i == player;

    if (column<mDim>(1)(input = x)) 
        col2 &= i == player;

    if (column<mDim>(2)( input = x)) 
        col3 &= i == player;
});
```

In my opinion, there is no problem with it. I'm even comfortable with it. However, for the next `for`-loop, the most ugly part in the `check()` function. It's checking in diagonal axes by hard-coding the possible position in a grid array:

```
    for (const auto& i : grid)
    {
        int x = j++;
        if (x == 0 || x == 4 || x == 8)
            diag1 &= i == player;
        if (x == 2 || x == 4 || x == 6)
            diag2 &= i == player;
    }
//ugly right!
```

The last `for`-loop is for checking by rows.

**Why this approach is better**

First of all, I removed both `for`-loops to be just one `for`-loop that takes care of checking any matches:

```
    std::for_each(grid.begin(), grid.end(),
        [&](char i)
    {
        int x = j++;

        // columns
        if (column<mDim>(0)(input = x)) // first column
            win[0] &= i == player;
        if (column<mDim>(1)(input = x))
            win[1] &= i == player;
        if (column<mDim>(2)(input = x))
            win[2] &= i == player;

        // rows
        if (row<mDim>(0)(input = x)) // first row
            win[3] &= i == player;
        if (row<mDim>(1)(input = x))
            win[4] &= i == player;
        if (row<mDim>(2)(input = x))
            win[5] &= i == player;

        // diagonals
        if (diagonal<mDim>(0)(input = x))
            win[6] &= i == player;
        if (diagonal<mDim>(2)(input = x))
            win[7] &= i == player;
    });
```

Also, I added 2 functors to take condition arguments and compute for matching:

```
// utility functor to compute matching condition by row
template<int dim>
struct row : public std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    row(int i) : rowNum(i){}
    bool operator() (int number)
    {
        return (std::abs(number / dim)  == rowNum);
    }
    int rowNum;
};

template<int dim>
struct diagonal : public std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    diagonal(int i) : diag(i){}
    bool operator() (int number)
    {
        switch (diag)
        {
        case 0:
            return ((std::abs(number / dim) - number % dim) == diag);
        case 2:
            return ((std::abs(number / dim) + number % dim) == diag);
        }

        return false; // for the warning in VC++ 2013
    }
    int diag;
};
```

I removed the old variables `row1`, `row2`, `row3`, `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, `diag1` and `diag2` and replaced them with an array that takes `bool` values.

```
std::array<bool, 8> win = 
{
    true, true, true,true,
    true, true, true, true
};
```

Now, it is much easier to minimize the hard-coding by control all constants with `mDim`

I believe this is a much better approach, in my opinion, to minimize hard-coding in game logic.

**Complete code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>

enum struct Player : char
{
    none = '-',
    first = 'X',
    second = 'O'
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Player p)
{
    return os << static_cast<char>(p);
}

class TicTacToe
{
public:
    TicTacToe(); 
    bool isFull() const;
    void draw() const;
    void turn(Player player);
    bool check(Player player) const;

private:
    bool applyMove(Player player, int position);

    static const std::size_t mDim = 3;
    std::array<Player, mDim * mDim> grid;
};

// utility functor to compute matching condition by column
template<int dim>
struct column : public std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    column(int i) : colNum(i){}
    bool operator() (int number) const
    { 
        return (number % dim == colNum); 
    }
    int colNum;
};

// utility functor to compute matching condition by row
template<int dim>
struct row : public std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    row(int i) : rowNum(i){}
    bool operator() (int number) const
    {
        return (std::abs(number / dim)  == rowNum);
    }
    int rowNum;
};

// utility functor to compute matching condition by diagonal
template<int dim>
struct diagonal : public std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    diagonal(int i) : diag(i){}
    bool operator() (int number) const
    {
        switch (diag)
        {
        case 0:
            return ((std::abs(number / dim) - number % dim) == diag);
        case 2:
            return ((std::abs(number / dim) + number % dim) == diag);
        }

        return false; // for the warning in VC++ 2013
    }
    int diag;
};

TicTacToe::TicTacToe() 
{ 
    grid.fill(Player::none);
}

bool TicTacToe::applyMove(Player player, int position)
{
    if (grid[position] != Player::none)
        return false;
    grid[position] = player;
    return true;
}

bool TicTacToe::isFull() const
{
    return 0 == std::count_if(grid.begin(), grid.end(),
        [](Player i)
    {
        return i == Player::none;
    });
}

bool TicTacToe::check(Player player) const
{
    column<mDim>::argument_type input; // one for all and all for one

    // check for row or column wins
    std::array<bool, 8> win;
    win.fill(true);

    int dim = mDim;
    int j = 0;

    // checking condition loop
    std::for_each(grid.begin(), grid.end(),
        [&](Player i)
    {
        int x = j++;

        // columns
        if (column<mDim>(0)(input = x))
            win[0] &= i == player;;
        if (column<mDim>(1)(input = x))
            win[1] &= i == player;
        if (column<mDim>(2)(input = x)) // first column
            win[2] &= i == player;

        // rows
        if (row<mDim>(0)(input = x)) // first row
            win[3] &= i == player;
        if (row<mDim>(1)(input = x))
            win[4] &= i == player;
        if (row<mDim>(2)(input = x))
            win[5] &= i == player;

        // diagonals
        if (diagonal<mDim>(0)(input = x))
            win[6] &= i == player;
        if (diagonal<mDim>(2)(input = x))
            win[7] &= i == player;
    });

    for (auto i : win)
    {
        if (i)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void TicTacToe::draw() const
{
    //Creating a onscreen grid
    std::cout << ' ';
    for (auto i = 1; i <= mDim; ++i)
        std::cout << "  " << i;

    int j = 0;
    char A = 'A';

    column<mDim>::argument_type input;

    for (auto i : grid)
    {
        if (column<mDim>(0)(input = j++))
            std::cout << "\n " << A++;

        std::cout << ' ' << i << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

void TicTacToe::turn(Player player)
{
    char row = 0;
    char column = 0;
    std::size_t position = 0;
    bool applied = false;

    std::cout << "\n" << player << ": Please play. \n";

    while (!applied)
    {
        std::cout << "Row(1,2,3,...): ";
        std::cin >> row;
        std::cout << player << ": Column(A,B,C,...): ";
        std::cin >> column;

        position = mDim * (std::toupper(column) - 'A') + (row - '1');

        if (position < grid.size())
        {
            applied = applyMove(player, position);

            if (!applied)
                std::cout << "Already Used. Try Again. \n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid position.  Try again.\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

class Game
{
public:
    Game() = default;
    void run();

private:
    TicTacToe ttt;
    std::array<Player, 2> players{ { Player::first, Player::second } };
    int player = 1;

    void resultScreen(bool winner);
    std::function<void()>       display = std::bind(&TicTacToe::draw, &ttt);
    std::function<void(Player)> turn    = std::bind(&TicTacToe::turn, &ttt, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<bool(Player)> win     = std::bind(&TicTacToe::check, &ttt, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<bool()>       full    = std::bind(&TicTacToe::isFull, &ttt);
};

void Game::run()
{
    while (!win(players[player]) && !full())
    {
        player ^= 1;
        display();
        turn(players[player]);
    }

    resultScreen(win(players[player]));
}

void Game::resultScreen(bool winner)
{
    display();

    if (winner)
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << players[player] << " is the Winner!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nTie game!\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.run();
}
```