# Tic-Tac-Toe in C++11 - follow-up

Tags: c++, game, c++11, tic-tac-toe

This is based on my first Tic-Tac-Toe game:

[Tic-Tac-Toe in C++11](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70593/tic-tac-toe-game-in-c11/70645#70645)

I have come up with different game logic for my game. I would like to know which one is more reliable and effective and how I can improve the whole game.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

class TicTacToe
{
public:
    bool isFull() const;
    void draw() const;
    void turn(char player);
    bool check(char player) const;

private:
    bool fill(char player, int position);

    static const std::size_t mDim = 3;
    std::array<char, mDim * mDim> grid
    { 
        {   
            '-', '-', '-',
            '-', '-', '-',
            '-', '-', '-' 
        } 
    };
};

template<std::size_t dim>
struct column : public std::unary_function<int, bool>
{
    column(int i) 
        : colNum(i)
    {}

    bool operator() (int number) 
    { 
        return (number % dim == colNum); 
    }

    int colNum;
};

struct pairCondition
{
    int number;
    char name;

    pairCondition(int number, char name)
        : number(number), name(name)
    {}

    bool operator== (const pairCondition& s) const
    {
        return name == s.name;
    }
};

bool checkCondition(const pairCondition& i, const std::array<int, 3>& a, char player)
{

    if (i.number == a[0] || i.number == a[1] || i.number == a[2])
        return i.name == player;
    else
        return i.name != player;

}

bool TicTacToe::fill(char player, int position)
{
    if (grid[position] != '-')
        return false;
    grid[position] = player;
    return true;
}

bool TicTacToe::isFull() const
{
    return 0 == std::count_if(grid.begin(), grid.end(),
        [](const char& i)
    {
        return i == '-';
    });
}

bool TicTacToe::check(char player) const
{
    typedef std::function<bool(pairCondition)> func;

    // rows
    bool row1 = true, row2 = true, row3 = true;

    std::array<int, 3> rows1 = { 0, 1, 2 };
    std::array<int, 3> rows2 = { 3, 4, 5 };
    std::array<int, 3> rows3 = { 6, 7, 8 };

    func rowf1 = std::bind(&checkCondition, std::placeholders::_1, rows1, player);
    func rowf2 = std::bind(&checkCondition, std::placeholders::_1, rows2, player);
    func rowf3 = std::bind(&checkCondition, std::placeholders::_1, rows3, player);

    // columns
    bool col1 = true, col2 = true, col3 = true;

    std::array<int, 3> columns1 = { 0, 3, 6 };
    std::array<int, 3> columns2 = { 1, 4, 7 };
    std::array<int, 3> columns3 = { 2, 5, 8 };

    func colf1 = std::bind(&checkCondition, std::placeholders::_1, columns1, player);
    func colf2 = std::bind(&checkCondition, std::placeholders::_1, columns2, player);
    func colf3 = std::bind(&checkCondition, std::placeholders::_1, columns3, player);

    // diagonals
    bool diag1 = true, diag2 = true;

    std::array<int, 3> diagonal1 = { 0, 4, 8 };
    std::array<int, 3> diagonal2 = { 2, 4, 6 };

    func diagf1 = std::bind(&checkCondition, std::placeholders::_1, diagonal1, player);
    func diagf2 = std::bind(&checkCondition, std::placeholders::_1, diagonal2, player);

    std::vector<pairCondition> v =
    {
        { 0, grid[0] }, { 1, grid[1] }, { 2, grid[2] },
        { 3, grid[3] }, { 4, grid[4] }, { 5, grid[5] },
        { 6, grid[6] }, { 7, grid[7] }, { 8, grid[8] }
    };

    for (const auto& i : v)
    {
        // rows conditions
        row1 &= rowf1(i);
        row2 &= rowf2(i);
        row3 &= rowf3(i);

        // columns conditions
        col1 &= colf1(i);
        col2 &= colf2(i);
        col3 &= colf3(i);

        // diagonals conditions
        diag1 &= diagf1(i);
        diag2 &= diagf2(i);
    };

    return (row1 || row2 || row3 ||
            col1 || col2 || col3 ||
            diag1 || diag2);
}

void TicTacToe::draw() const
{
    //Creating a onscreen grid
    std::cout << ' ';
    for (std::size_t i = 1; i <= mDim; ++i)
        std::cout << "  " << i;

    int j = 0;
    char A = 'A';

    column<mDim>::argument_type input;

    for (auto& i : grid)
    {
        if (column<mDim>(0)(input = j++))
            std::cout << "\n " << A++;

        std::cout << ' ' << i << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

void TicTacToe::turn(char player)
{
    char row = 0;
    char column = 0;
    std::size_t position = 0;
    bool applied = false;

    std::cout << "\n" << player << ": Please play. \n";

    while (!applied) 
    {
        std::cout << "Row(1,2,3,...): ";
        std::cin >> row;
        std::cout << player << ": Column(A,B,C,...): ";
        std::cin >> column;

        position = mDim * (std::toupper(column) - 'A') + (row - '1');

        if (position < grid.size()) 
        {
            applied = fill(player, position);

            if (!applied)
                std::cout << "Already Used. Try Again. \n";
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid position.  Try again.\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

class Game
{
public:
    Game() = default;
    void run();

private:
    TicTacToe ttt;
    std::array<char, 2> players{ { 'X', 'O' } };
    int player = 1;

    void resultScreen();
    std::function<void()>       display = std::bind(&TicTacToe::draw, &ttt);
    std::function<void(char)>   turn    = std::bind(&TicTacToe::turn, &ttt, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<bool(char)>   win     = std::bind(&TicTacToe::check, &ttt, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<bool()>       full    = std::bind(&TicTacToe::isFull, &ttt);
};


void Game::run()
{
    while (!win(players[player]) && !full() )
    {
        player ^= 1;
        display();
        turn(players[player]);
    }

    resultScreen();
}

void Game::resultScreen()
{
    display();

    if (win)
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << players[player] << " is the Winner!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nTie game!\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.run();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a few tidbits that could help. Nothing big, but things that you can improve as you code without having to overthink them:

- Use `constexpr` to represent compile-time constants. `static const` works but `constexpr` pops into to head and screams "compile time!" when you read it:

  ```
  static constexpr std::size_t mDim = 3;
  ```
- `column::operator()` should be `const`-qualified since it does not alter the state of `column`:

  ```
  bool operator() (int number) const
  { 
      return (number % dim == colNum); 
  }
  ```
- [`unary_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/unary_function) and [`binary_function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/binary_function) are deprecated since C++11 and will be removed from the standard in C++17. Therefore, you should avoid using them. The easy fix is to define `result_type` and `argument_type` by hand (which is rahter quick) or to simply use the types at the call point where you probably know them.
- You could consider making the types `column` and `pairCondition` immutable by making their members `const`. Beforehand, really think about whether you want them to be immutable. It could make sense for `column` since functions are often immutable and this is a functor type.
- I don't think that you want to represent any other cells thant "no player", "player 1" and "player 2". Therefore, you could probably use an `enum struct` to represent the accepted values in your grid instead of a `char`:

  ```
  enum struct player: char
  {
      none = '-',
      first = 'X',
      second = 'O'
  };
  ```

  Using an `enum struct` would ensure that you don't use any other magic value and would answer the question "what does this `char` represent?" when reading the code. If you really need to access the underlying type of the `enum` at different places, then use a simple `enum` instead of an `enum struct`.

Comment: thanks for your answer. i checked it as answer. but constexpr not recognized in VC++ 2013 which i'm using now.

Comment: @Morwenn: What do you think about `const char players[3]{ 'X', 'O', '-' };` as an alternative to the `enum struct`?  That way the code could continue to use `player ^= 1;` to change players.

Comment: @Edward .. even with 'enum struct player: char'. still the code can use 'player ^=1'

Comment: @Edward .. please check my code in gist: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e04dff4659fa90f364f0

Comment: @MORTAL That's probably an MSVC extension, using `^=` with an `enum struct` should be a hard error. Anyway, you can still overload `operator^=` for `player` or simply use an `enum` instead of an `enum struct` even though it lessens type safety.

Comment: @Morwenn ... thank you for clarify enum. but i ran it in my code it seems work fine. i will keep your warning in my mind. once again thank you

Comment: @Morwenn ... sorry,,, i have to tell you that `player` is `unsigned int` it works as index in array of enum `array<Player, 2>` not the `enum struct Player: char` itself. i was confusing about what you mean until i discovered that you were mistaken about our `player` lol. i felt guilty about it. sorry for confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Your `check()` is still completly hardcoded to have a dimension of 3x3. I think it's even worse, as in more hardcoded, than the previous one.

Your class has a constant `mDim`. Define your rows, columns and diagonals using that constant. The number of rows and collumns is determined by `mDim`. Also the length of each row, column and diagonal is determined by 'mDim'.

The same goes for `checkCondition()`. The 3 is hardcoded but should be governed by `mDim`.

Try making `mDim` selectable in the constructor and play a standard 3x3 game of Tic-Tac-Toe and a larger 4x4 game of Tic-Tac-Toe-Tuz to see if you have have removed the hardcoded 3 everywhere.

---

If you want to go one step further you could remove the hardcoding of the board being a square and the board being 2 dimensional. Ever played 3D Tic-Tac-Toe?

Comment: you are absolutely right about this example is more worse than previous. i coded it for some one ask to make one for loop and separate arrays for win-condition.
i knew this method will lead to more hard coding which why i came here to get help or hint how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure your new `checkCondition` is an improvement.  Compare the long and complex code you've got to something like this:

```
bool TicTacToe::isWinner(char player) const
{
    // check for row or column wins
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < mDim; ++i){
        bool rowwin = true;
        bool colwin = true;
        for (unsigned j=0; j < mDim; ++j) {
            rowwin &= grid[i*mDim+j] == player;
            colwin &= grid[j*mDim+i] == player;
        }
        if (colwin || rowwin) 
            return true;
    }
    // check for diagonal wins
    bool diagwin = true;
    for (unsigned i=0; i < mDim; ++i) 
        diagwin &= grid[i*mDim+i] == player;
    if (diagwin) 
        return true;
    diagwin = true;
    for (unsigned i=0; i < mDim; ++i) 
        diagwin &= grid[i*mDim+(mDim-i-1)] == player;
    return diagwin; 
}
```

Which is easier to understand?  Which is shorter?

Comment: yes. i'm totally satisfied and agree with your game-logic version.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt in minimizing hard-coding of this code, as well as improving my code base on what I have learned so far from @Jamal and @Edward in my previous post.

**Proper naming for classes and its member functions and variables**

I still have difficulty choosing the proper name to the classes and its members. It's a BIG problem for anyone for whom the English language is not his native language.
So I have renamed some functions to imply the exact meaning of its name. For instance, `fill()` in `TicTacToe` class becomes `applyMove`. Also, all member variables using prefixes such as `mGrid`, `mDash`, `mFree` and `mDim`.

Also, I changed struct `WinCondition` to be struct `Pair`.

It's even better to use extended prefixes to member variables like `s` for static and `c` for constant.

**Create and use a constructor for `TicTacToe`**

It's great to initialize `std::array` in the constructor body rather than initialize it in the declaration part of the class. So, the `TicTacToe` constructor will be like this:

```
TicTacToe::TicTacToe() 
{ 
    mGrid.fill(mDash);
}
```

and it simply defines `mGrid` like this:

```
std::array<char, mDim * mDim> mGrid;
```

**Simplifying and optimizing**

I changed `isFull()` to be much simpler by making a new variable `mFree`:

```
bool TicTacToe::isFull() const
{
    return mFree == 0;
}
```

Also, I changed the conditional statement in `draw()`.

```
column<mDim>::argument_type input;

for (auto& i : grid)
{
    int x = j++;
    if (column<mDim>(0)(input = x ))
        std::cout << "\n " << A++;

    std::cout << ' ' << i << ' ';
}
```

to become like this:

```
for (auto i : mGrid)
{
    if (j++ % mDim == 0)
        std::cout << "\n " << A++;

    std::cout << ' ' << i << ' ';
}
```

I removed `struct column` as it's no longer be needed in the code.

**Minimizing hard-coding**

To accomplish this, I need rearrange the `check()` function body. As it looks, it has huge blocks of variable declarations and definitions, so a `struct` is needed. I created a struct called `WinCondition` like this:

```
template<int dim>
struct WinCondition
{
    typedef std::function<bool(Pair, char)> func;
    typedef std::array<int, dim> Array;
    WinCondition()
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
        {
            // set rows
            const int j = i;
            rows1[j] = i;
            rows2[j] = i + 1 * dim;
            rows3[j] = i + 2 * dim;

            // set columns
            columns1[j] = i * dim;
            columns2[j] = 1 + i * dim;
            columns3[j] = 2 + i * dim;

            // set diagonals
            diagonal1[j] = 4 * i ;
            diagonal2[j] = 2 * (i + 1);

        }

        colf1 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, columns1, std::placeholders::_2);
        colf2 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, columns2, std::placeholders::_2);
        colf3 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, columns3, std::placeholders::_2);

        rowf1 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, rows1, std::placeholders::_2);
        rowf2 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, rows2, std::placeholders::_2);
        rowf3 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, rows3, std::placeholders::_2);


        diagf1 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, diagonal1, std::placeholders::_2);
        diagf2 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, diagonal2, std::placeholders::_2);
    }

    Array rows1, rows2, rows3, 
          columns1, columns2, columns3, 
          diagonal1, diagonal2;


    func colf1, colf2, colf3,
         rowf1, rowf2, rowf3,
         diagf1, diagf2;
};
```

Now, in `check()` function would be like this

```
bool TicTacToe::check(char player) const
{
    std::array<bool, 8> winner;
    winner.fill(true);

    std::vector<Pair> v;

    for (auto i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        v.emplace_back(Pair(i, mGrid[i]));

    for (auto i : v)
    {
        // rows conditions
        winner[0] &= win.rowf1(i, player);
        winner[1] &= win.rowf2(i, player);
        winner[2] &= win.rowf3(i, player);

        // columns conditions
        winner[3] &= win.colf1(i, player);
        winner[4] &= win.colf2(i, player);
        winner[5] &= win.colf3(i, player);

        // diagonals conditions
        winner[6] &= win.diagf1(i, player);
        winner[7] &= win.diagf2(i, player);
    }

    for (auto i : winner)
    {
        if (i)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now, it's much easier to minimize hard-coding any further.

Thanks to @Morwenn, I'm now a bit familiar with scoped enumerations, a new kind of enumeration in C++ (documented [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum)).

Thanks to @Goswin, Now `check()` is ok.

**Complete code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <vector>

enum struct Player: char
{
    none = '-',
    first = 'X',
    second = 'O'
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Player p)
{
    return os << static_cast<char>(p);
}

struct Pair
{
    int mNumber;
    Player mName; 
    Pair(int number, Player name)
        : mNumber(number), mName(name)
    {}

    bool operator== (const Pair& s) const
    {
        return mName == s.mName;
    }
};

template<int dim>
bool checkCondition(const Pair& i, const std::array<int, dim>& a, Player player)
{

    if (i.mNumber == a[0] || i.mNumber == a[1] || i.mNumber == a[2])
        return i.mName == player;
    else
        return i.mName != player;

}

template<int dim>
struct WinCondition
{
    typedef std::function<bool(Pair, Player)> func;
    typedef std::array<int, dim> Array;
    WinCondition()
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < dim; ++i)
        {
            // set rows
            const int j = i;
            rows1[j] = i;
            rows2[j] = i + 1 * dim;
            rows3[j] = i + 2 * dim;

            // set columns
            columns1[j] = i * dim;
            columns2[j] = 1 + i * dim;
            columns3[j] = 2 + i * dim;

            // set diagonals
            diagonal1[j] = 4 * i ;
            diagonal2[j] = 2 * (i + 1);
        }

        colf1 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, columns1, std::placeholders::_2);
        colf2 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, columns2, std::placeholders::_2);
        colf3 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, columns3, std::placeholders::_2);

        rowf1 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, rows1, std::placeholders::_2);
        rowf2 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, rows2, std::placeholders::_2);
        rowf3 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, rows3, std::placeholders::_2);

        diagf1 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, diagonal1, std::placeholders::_2);
        diagf2 = std::bind(&checkCondition<dim>, std::placeholders::_1, diagonal2, std::placeholders::_2);
    }

    Array rows1, rows2, rows3, 
          columns1, columns2, columns3, 
          diagonal1, diagonal2;

    func colf1, colf2, colf3,
         rowf1, rowf2, rowf3,
         diagf1, diagf2;
};

class TicTacToe
{
public:
    TicTacToe();
    bool isFull() const;
    void draw() const;
    void turn(Player player);
    bool check(Player player) const;

private:
    bool applyMove(Player player, int position);

    static const unsigned mDim = 3;
    //const char mDash = '-';
    unsigned mFree = mDim * mDim;
    std::array<Player, mDim * mDim> mGrid;
    WinCondition<mDim> win;
};


TicTacToe::TicTacToe() 
    : win()
{ 
    mGrid.fill(Player::none);
}

bool TicTacToe::applyMove(Player player, int position)
{
    if (mGrid[position] != Player::none)
        return false;
    mGrid[position] = player;
    --mFree;
    return true;
}

bool TicTacToe::isFull() const
{
    return mFree == 0;
}

bool TicTacToe::check(Player player) const
{
    std::array<bool, 8> winner;
    winner.fill(true);

    std::vector<Pair> v;

    for (auto i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
        v.emplace_back(Pair(i, mGrid[i]));

    int j = 0;
    for (auto i : v)
    {
        // rows conditions
        winner[j++] &= win.rowf1(i, player);
        winner[j++] &= win.rowf2(i, player);
        winner[j++] &= win.rowf3(i, player);

        // columns conditions
        winner[j++] &= win.colf1(i, player);
        winner[j++] &= win.colf2(i, player);
        winner[j++] &= win.colf3(i, player);

        // diagonals conditions
        winner[j++] &= win.diagf1(i, player);
        winner[j++] &= win.diagf2(i, player);

        // correction
        j = 0;
    }

    for (auto i : winner)
    {
        if (i)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void TicTacToe::draw() const
{
    //Creating a onscreen grid
    std::cout << ' ';
    for (auto i = 1; i <= mDim; ++i)
        std::cout << "  " << i;

    int j = 0;
    char A = 'A';

    for (auto i : mGrid)
    {
        if (j++ % mDim == 0)
            std::cout << "\n " << A++;

        std::cout << ' ' << i << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

void TicTacToe::turn(Player player)
{
    char row = 0;
    char column = 0;
    unsigned position = 0;
    bool applied = false;

    std::cout << "\n" << player << ": Please play. \n";

    while (!applied) 
    {
        std::cout << "Row(1,2,3,...): ";
        std::cin >> row;
        std::cout << player << ": Column(A,B,C,...): ";
        std::cin >> column;

        position = mDim * (std::toupper(column) - 'A') + (row - '1');

        if (position < mGrid.size())
        {
            applied = applyMove(player, position);

            if (!applied)
                std::cout << "Already Used. Try Again. \n";
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid position.  Try again.\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

class Game
{
public:
    Game() = default;
    void run();

private:
    TicTacToe ttt;
    std::array<Player, 2> players{ { Player::first, Player::second } };
    int player = 1;

    void resultScreen(bool winner);
    std::function<void()>       display = std::bind(&TicTacToe::draw, &ttt);
    std::function<void(Player)> turn    = std::bind(&TicTacToe::turn, &ttt, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<bool(Player)> win     = std::bind(&TicTacToe::check, &ttt, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<bool()>       full    = std::bind(&TicTacToe::isFull, &ttt);
};

void Game::run()
{
    while (!win(players[player]) && !full() )
    {
        player ^= 1;
        display();
        turn(players[player]);
    }

    resultScreen(win(players[player]));

}

void Game::resultScreen(bool winner)
{
    display();

    if (winner)
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << players[player] << " is the Winner!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nTie game!\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.run();

}
```

Comment: You have still hardcoded 8 victory conditions. That should be width + height + 2 many.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow ... thanks, i have corrected now