# Tic-Tac-Toe in C++11 - follow-up 2

Tags: c++, game, c++11, tic-tac-toe

Previous question:

[Tic-Tac-Toe in C++11 - follow-up](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70650/tic-tac-toe-in-c11-follow-up)

Is there any way to improve this code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>

enum struct Player : char
{
    none    = '-',
    first   = 'X',
    second  = 'O'
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Player p)
{
    return os << static_cast<char>(p);
}

enum struct Type : int
{
    row = 0,
    column = 1,
    diagonal = 2
};

enum struct Lines : int
{
    first   = 0,
    second  = 1,
    third   = 2
};

class TicTacToe
{
public:
    TicTacToe(); 
    bool isFull() const;
    void draw() const;
    void turn(Player player);
    bool check(Player player) const;

private:
    bool applyMove(Player player, int position);

    static const std::size_t mDim = 3;
    std::array<Player, mDim * mDim> mGrid;
};

// utility functor to compute matching condition
template<int dim>
struct Match 
{
    Match(Type t, Lines i) : mCategory(t), mNumber(i){}
    bool operator() (int number) const
    {
        switch (mCategory)
        {
        case Type::row:
            return (std::abs(number / dim) == static_cast<int>(mNumber));
        case Type::column:
            return (number % dim == static_cast<int>(mNumber));
        case Type::diagonal:
            if (mNumber == Lines::first)
                return ((std::abs(number / dim) - number % dim) == static_cast<int>(mNumber));
            else
                return ((std::abs(number / dim) + number % dim) == static_cast<int>(mNumber));
        }

        return false; 
    }
    Type mCategory;
    Lines mNumber;
};

TicTacToe::TicTacToe() 
{ 
    mGrid.fill(Player::none);
}

bool TicTacToe::applyMove(Player player, int position)
{
    if (mGrid[position] != Player::none)
        return false;
    mGrid[position] = player;
    return true;
}

bool TicTacToe::isFull() const
{
    return 0 == std::count_if(mGrid.begin(), mGrid.end(),
        [](Player i)
    {
        return i == Player::none;
    });
}

bool TicTacToe::check(Player player) const
{
    // check for row or column wins
    std::array<bool, 8> win;
    win.fill(true);

    int j = 0;

    // checking condition loop
    std::for_each(mGrid.begin(), mGrid.end(),
        [&](Player i)
    {
        int x = j++;

        // columns
        if (Match<mDim>(Type::column, Lines::first)(x))
            win[0] &= i == player;;
        if (Match<mDim>(Type::column, Lines::second)(x))
            win[1] &= i == player;
        if (Match<mDim>(Type::column, Lines::third)(x)) 
            win[2] &= i == player;

        // rows
        if (Match<mDim>(Type::row, Lines::first)(x))
            win[3] &= i == player;
        if (Match<mDim>(Type::row, Lines::second)(x))
            win[4] &= i == player;
        if (Match<mDim>(Type::row, Lines::third)(x))
            win[5] &= i == player;

        // diagonals
        if (Match<mDim>(Type::diagonal, Lines::first)(x))
            win[6] &= i == player;
        if (Match<mDim>(Type::diagonal, Lines::third)(x))
            win[7] &= i == player;
    });

    for (auto i : win)
    {
        if (i)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void TicTacToe::draw() const
{
    //Creating a onscreen grid
    std::cout << ' ';
    for (auto i = 1; i <= mDim; ++i)
        std::cout << "  " << i;

    int j = 0;
    char A = 'A';

    for (auto i : mGrid)
    {
        if (Match<mDim>(Type::column, Lines::first)(j++))
            std::cout << "\n " << A++;

        std::cout << ' ' << i << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

void TicTacToe::turn(Player player)
{
    char row = 0;
    char column = 0;
    std::size_t position = 0;
    bool applied = false;

    std::cout << "\n" << player << ": Please play. \n";

    while (!applied)
    {
        std::cout << "Row(1,2,3,...): ";
        std::cin >> row;
        std::cout << player << ": Column(A,B,C,...): ";
        std::cin >> column;

        position = mDim * (std::toupper(column) - 'A') + (row - '1');

        if (position < mGrid.size())
        {
            applied = applyMove(player, position);

            if (!applied)
                std::cout << "Already Used. Try Again. \n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid position.  Try again.\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

class Game
{
public:
    Game() = default;
    void run();

private:
    TicTacToe mTicTacToe;
    std::array<Player, 2> mPlayers{ { Player::first, Player::second } };
    int mPlayer = 1;

    void resultScreen(bool winner);
    std::function<void()>       display = std::bind(&TicTacToe::draw, &mTicTacToe);
    std::function<void(Player)> turn    = std::bind(&TicTacToe::turn, &mTicTacToe, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<bool(Player)> win     = std::bind(&TicTacToe::check, &mTicTacToe, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<bool()>       full    = std::bind(&TicTacToe::isFull, &mTicTacToe);
};

void Game::run()
{
    while (!win(mPlayers[mPlayer]) && !full())
    {
        mPlayer ^= 1;
        display();
        turn(mPlayers[mPlayer]);
    }

    resultScreen(win(mPlayers[mPlayer]));
}

void Game::resultScreen(bool winner)
{
    display();

    if (winner)
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << mPlayers[mPlayer] << " is the Winner!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nTie game!\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.run();
}
```

Comment: Yes, this can be improved to be able to handle e.g. a 4x4 board. See any of the previous tic-tac-toe questions for details.

Comment: And some new improvement: Add an AI for single player games.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow .. AL is so interesting subject i'm currently reading related subject.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow ... to make this code be able to handle a mesh nXn seems impossible with `enum struct`.

Comment: Indeed. Using enums seems to be going the wrong way. That hardcodes things. Using indexes and iterators makes it flexible. Define a row, column and diagonal class (lets call that a `Line`) and give TicTacToe an iterator over all rows, all columns and all diagonals (all lines). Row, column and diagonal again can have an iterator over its fields. You then can check for win with `for (auto line : TicTacToe.lines()) { bool win = True; for (auto field : line.fields()) { if {field.player() != player) { win = false; break; } } if (win) return true; } return false; }`

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow ... i make it work to handle any mesh nXn. would you check it whether it's ok or need further work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some things that may allow you to improve your code:

### Separate responsibilities

The [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) design pattern is often useful for programs like this.  Because the view in this case is essentially just printing the board to `std::cout`, we can simplify a bit and just have a model, the `TicTacToe` class, and a controller, the `Game` class.  Here's what the `TicTacToe` class looks like:

```
class TicTacToe
{
public:
    TicTacToe() = delete;
    TicTacToe(const TicTacToe &t) = delete;
    TicTacToe(const TicTacToe &&t) = delete;
    TicTacToe(char ch, std::size_t dim) 
        : mDim(dim), emptychar(ch), remaining(mDim*mDim), grid(remaining, emptychar) 
    { }
    bool isNotFull() const { return remaining; }
    bool isWinner(char player) const;
    bool applyMove(char player, unsigned row, unsigned column);
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const TicTacToe &t) {
        out << ' ';
        for (std::size_t i = 1; i <= t.mDim; ++i)
            out << "  " << i;
        std::size_t j = 0;
        char A = 'A';
        for (auto& i : t.grid)
        {
            if (j == 0) {
                out << "\n " << A++;
                j = mDim;
            }
            --j;
            out << ' ' << i << ' ';
        }
        return out << "\n\n";
    }
private:
    const std::size_t mDim;
    const char emptychar;
    unsigned remaining;
    std::vector<char> grid;
};
```

There are some differences in this class compared to yours, so I'll point out the salient features.

### Delete automatic functions which are not wanted

The way I've defined the `TicTacToe` class requires values to be passed to the constructor. For that reason, I've deleted the default constructor, the copy constructor and the move constructor.  This prevents the class from being misused and alerts the user of the class that some things are not supported.

### Isolate the internal representation from the interface

The game is played on a square grid and not a linear array (even though that may be the internal representation), so the `applyMove` function in the revised version takes `row` and `column` arguments rather than a linear `position` value.

### Allow for dynamic sizing

The dimension of the board in the revised version of the `TicTacToe` class is a `const` value that is initialized with a value passed to the constructor.  This allows for more than one size game to be played without recompiling.  Also, this required changing from a `std::array` to a `std::vector`.

### Allow for any character representations

This version does not specify the representations for an empty square, or any of the player tokens.  In particular, the `emptychar` member function is initialized by the constructor. Perhaps more interesting is the fact that this class allows for more than two players.  This can be seen most easily in the `applyMove` member function:

```
// Returns `false` if requested move was applied, otherwise true
bool TicTacToe::applyMove(char player, unsigned row, unsigned column)
{
    unsigned position = row + mDim * column;
   if ((position > grid.size()) || (grid[position] != emptychar))
        return true;
    grid[position] = player;
    --remaining;
    return false;
}
```

### Define logical functions in a way that makes them most useful

If we look at the original `isFull` routine, it was always being used as `!isFull()` so it seems that what's actualy more useful is a method to check if the grid is not full.  For this reason, the function is now `isNotFull()` in the redefined version.

### Avoid inefficient algorithms

The original `isFull` routine counts empty squares each time it is called, but a more efficient (and simpler) way to do this is to simply keep a running count as the game is played.

### Use clear function names

The original code has a function named `check` but it's not clear what it checks.  I've renamed it to `isWinner` so that it's very clear now that it's checking to see if a particular player is a winner or not.  I've also reimplemented it to work simply and efficiently no matter what size the array happens to be:

```
// returns true if the player is a winner
bool TicTacToe::isWinner(char player) const
{
    // check for row or column wins
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < mDim; ++i){
        bool rowwin = true;
        bool colwin = true;
        for (unsigned j=0; j < mDim; ++j) {
            rowwin &= grid[i*mDim+j] == player;
            colwin &= grid[j*mDim+i] == player;
        }
        if (colwin || rowwin) 
            return true;
    }
    // check for diagonal wins
    bool diagwin = true;
    for (unsigned i=0; i < mDim; ++i) 
        diagwin &= grid[i*mDim+i] == player;
    if (diagwin) 
        return true;
    diagwin = true;
    for (unsigned i=0; i < mDim; ++i) 
        diagwin &= grid[i*mDim+(mDim-i-1)] == player;
    return diagwin; 
}
```

### Revise the `Game` class to be a controller

In the interest in clearly separating responsibilities of the classes, here is the revised `Game` class:

```
class Game
{
public:
    Game(std::size_t dim=3) : ttt(players[2], dim), player(1) {}
    void run();
    void run(const char *move);
    void turn();
    void showResult() const;
private:
    const char players[3] = { 'X', 'O', '-' };
    TicTacToe ttt;
    int player;
};
```

The most significant change here is that the `turn` method is a method of `Game` rather than of `TicTacToe`.  This is important because the controller actually controls the game; the model simply reacts to the applied controls.  This makes some alternatives much easier to implement as I'll describe.

### Put the player character representations within the `Game` class

The character representations for each player and an empty space are all solely concerns of the `Game` class.  They don't need to be in global space as originally defined.

### Validate user input carefully

The current code accepts such inputs as (0,B) which should be rejected.  The revised code fixes this:

```
void Game::turn()
{
    char row = 0;
    char column = 0;

    std::cout << "\n" << players[player] << ": Please play. \n";

    for (bool pending = true; pending; ) 
    {
        std::cout << "Row(1,2,3,...): ";
        std::cin >> row;
        std::cout << players[player] << ": Column(A,B,C,...): ";
        std::cin >> column;

        column = std::toupper(column) - 'A';
        row -= '1';

        pending = column < 0 || row < 0 || ttt.applyMove(players[player], row, column);
        if (pending)
            std::cout << "Invalid position.  Try again.\n"; 
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}
```

Note that it also changes the sense of the boolean variable from `applied` to `pending` which somewhat simplifies the code and requires no negations.

### Eliminate pointless obfuscation

The use of `std::bind` is really not needed in this program and makes the program that much harder to read and understand.  The revised version of `run` doesn't need them and is easy to read and understand:

```
void Game::run()
{
    while (!ttt.isWinner(players[player]) && ttt.isNotFull())
    {
        player ^= 1;
        std::cout << ttt;
        turn();
    }
    showResult();
}
```

### Use `const` where possible

The `resultScreen` function doesn't and shouldn't modify the underlying `Game` class, and so it should be declared `const`.  Also, I've changed the name of the function to a more desscriptive `showResult` and eliminated the need to pass a variable.

```
void Game::showResult() const
{
    std::cout << ttt;
    if (ttt.isWinner(players[player]))
        std::cout << "\n" << players[player] << " is the Winner!\n";
    else 
        std::cout << "\nTie game!\n";
}
```

Note that this code only yields correct results when the game has already ended; one could add a check `ttt.isNotFull()` to handle any mid-game requests for results.

### Consider having the computer play by itself

By separating the `turn` function in `Game` from the `applyMove` function in `TicTacToe`, we have the first step toward having the potential for the computer to play against a human player.  I haven't implemented that, but I did implement a means by which a game can be run automatically, given a fixed series of moves.  That function looks like this:

```
void Game::run(const char *move)
{
    unsigned row, column;
    while (!ttt.isWinner(players[player]) && ttt.isNotFull() && *move)
    {
        player ^= 1;
        std::cout << ttt;
        row = *move++ - '1';
        column = std::toupper(*move++) - 'A';
        std::cout << "Applying " << players[player] << " to " 
            << row+1 << static_cast<char>('A'+column) << "\n";
        ttt.applyMove(players[player], row, column);
    }
    showResult();
}
```

Note that this part of the code lacks much in the way of error handling, but it's meant solely as illustration.

### Putting it all together

Here's a sample `main` function that plays one 3x3 tie game automatically, and then allows for two humans to play a 4x4 game against each other:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>

// TicTacToe and Game classes go here

int main()
{
    Game game1;
    game1.run("2B1A2A2C1C3A3B1B3C");
    Game game2(4);
    game2.run();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have deleted `enum struct Lines : int` because it would be impossible to handle nth line numbers. Then I made the code into a generic form by templating `Tictactoe`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>

enum struct Player : char
{
    none    = '-',
    first   = 'X',
    second  = 'O'
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Player p)
{
    return os << static_cast<char>(p);
}

enum struct Type : int
{
    row         = 0,
    column      = 1,
    diagonal    = 2
};

template<int mesh>
class TicTacToe
{
public:
    TicTacToe(); 
    bool isFull() const;
    void draw() const;
    void turn(Player player);
    bool check(Player player) const;

private:
    bool applyMove(Player player, int position);

    std::array<Player, mesh * mesh> mGrid;
};

// utility functor to compute matching condition
template<int mesh>
struct Match 
{
    Match(Type t, int i) : mCategory(t), mNumber(i){}
    bool operator() (int number) const
    {
        switch (mCategory)
        {
        case Type::row:
            return (std::abs(number / mesh) == mNumber);
        case Type::column:
            return (number % mesh == mNumber);
        case Type::diagonal:
            if (mNumber == 0)
                return ((std::abs(number / mesh) - number % mesh) == mNumber);
             if (mNumber == 1)
                 return ((std::abs(number / mesh) + number % mesh) == mNumber + mesh - 2);
        }

        return false; 
    }
    Type mCategory;
    int mNumber;
};

template<int mesh>
TicTacToe<mesh>::TicTacToe()
{ 
    mGrid.fill(Player::none);
}

template<int mesh>
bool TicTacToe<mesh>::applyMove(Player player, int position)
{
    if (mGrid[position] != Player::none)
        return false;
    mGrid[position] = player;
    return true;
}

template<int mesh>
bool TicTacToe<mesh>::isFull() const
{
    return 0 == std::count_if(mGrid.begin(), mGrid.end(),
        [](Player i)
    {
        return i == Player::none;
    });
}

template<int mesh>
bool TicTacToe<mesh>::check(Player player) const
{
    // check for row or column wins
    std::array<bool, 2 * (mesh + 1)> win;
    win.fill(true);

    int j = 0;

    // checking condition loop
    std::for_each(mGrid.begin(), mGrid.end(),
        [&](Player i)
    {
        int x = j++;

        for (auto k = 0; k < mesh; ++k){
            if (Match<mesh>(Type::column, k)(x))
                win[k] &= i == player;

            if (Match<mesh>(Type::row, k)(x))
                win[mesh + k] &= i == player;

            if (Match<mesh>(Type::diagonal, k)(x)){
                if (k < 2)
                    win[2 * mesh + k] &= i == player;
            }
        }   
    });

    for (auto i : win)
    {
        if (i)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

template<int mesh>
void TicTacToe<mesh>::draw() const
{
    //Creating a onscreen grid
    std::cout << ' ';
    for (auto i = 1; i <= mesh; ++i)
        std::cout << "  " << i;

    int j = 0;
    char A = 'A';

    for (auto i : mGrid)
    {
        if (Match<mesh>(Type::column, 0)(j++))
            std::cout << "\n " << A++;

        std::cout << ' ' << i << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

template<int mesh>
void TicTacToe<mesh>::turn(Player player)
{
    char row = 0;
    char column = 0;
    std::size_t position = 0;
    bool applied = false;

    std::cout << "\n" << player << ": Please play. \n";

    while (!applied)
    {
        std::cout << "Row(1,2,3,...): ";
        std::cin >> row;
        std::cout << player << ": Column(A,B,C,...): ";
        std::cin >> column;

        position = mesh * (std::toupper(column) - 'A') + (row - '1');

        if (position < mGrid.size())
        {
            applied = applyMove(player, position);

            if (!applied)
                std::cout << "Already Used. Try Again. \n";
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid position.  Try again.\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

class Game
{
public:
    Game() = default;
    void run();

private:
    static const std::size_t mMesh = 4;
    TicTacToe<mMesh> mTicTacToe;
    std::array<Player, 2> mPlayers{ { Player::first, Player::second } };
    int mPlayer = 1;

    void resultScreen(bool winner);
    std::function<void()>       display = std::bind(&TicTacToe<mMesh>::draw, &mTicTacToe);
    std::function<void(Player)> turn    = std::bind(&TicTacToe<mMesh>::turn, &mTicTacToe, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<bool(Player)> win     = std::bind(&TicTacToe<mMesh>::check, &mTicTacToe, std::placeholders::_1);
    std::function<bool()>       full    = std::bind(&TicTacToe<mMesh>::isFull, &mTicTacToe);
};

void Game::run()
{
    while (!win(mPlayers[mPlayer]) && !full())
    {
        mPlayer ^= 1;
        display();
        turn(mPlayers[mPlayer]);
    }

    resultScreen(win(mPlayers[mPlayer]));
}

void Game::resultScreen(bool winner)
{
    display();

    if (winner)
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << mPlayers[mPlayer] << " is the Winner!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nTie game!\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.run();
}
```

Comment: If you want to do it that way, with `match`, you might want to look into using `std::valarray` in conjunction with [`slice::stride`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/valarray/slice/stride/).

Comment: @Edward ... thanks for informative answer i have voted it up and checked it as answer. in optimization purpose, your answer will be perfect. i never knew about `std::valarray` and `slice::stride` before. it seems can be used in this code. i will try it, if it's worked. then, no need to reinvent the wheel.