# Tic-Tac-Toe in C++11 - follow-up 3

Tags: c++, game, c++11, tic-tac-toe

Previous question:

[Tic-Tac-Toe in C++11 - follow-up 2](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/70933/tic-tac-toe-in-c11-follow-up-2)

Here, AI is being implemented.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <ctime>

template <typename T>
T getRandom(T min, T max)
{
    return (rand() % (max + 1 - min) + min);
}

enum struct Player : char
{
    none = '-',
    first = 'X',
    second = 'O'
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Player p)
{
    return os << static_cast<char>(p);
}

enum struct Type : int
{
    row = 0,
    column = 1,
    diagonal = 2
};

template<int mesh>
class TicTacToe
{
public:
    TicTacToe();
    TicTacToe(const TicTacToe &t) = delete;
    TicTacToe(const TicTacToe &&t) = delete;

    bool isFull() const;
    void draw() const;
    bool isWinner(Player player) const;
    bool applyMove(Player player, unsigned row, unsigned column);

private:
    unsigned remaining = mesh * mesh;
    std::array<Player, mesh * mesh> mGrid;
};

// utility functor to compute matching condition
template<int mesh>
struct Match
{
    Match(Type t, int i) : mCategory(t), mNumber(i){}
    bool operator() (int number) const
    {
        switch (mCategory)
        {
        case Type::row:
            return (std::abs(number / mesh) == mNumber);
        case Type::column:
            return (number % mesh == mNumber);
        case Type::diagonal:
            if (mNumber == 0)
                return ((std::abs(number / mesh) - number % mesh) == mNumber);
            if (mNumber == 1)
                return ((std::abs(number / mesh) + number % mesh) == mNumber + mesh - 2);
        }

        return false;
    }
    Type mCategory;
    int mNumber;
};

template<int mesh>
TicTacToe<mesh>::TicTacToe()
{
    mGrid.fill(Player::none);
}

template<int mesh>
bool TicTacToe<mesh>::applyMove(Player player, unsigned row, unsigned column)
{
    unsigned position = row + mesh * column;
    if ((position > mGrid.size()) || (mGrid[position] != Player::none))
        return true;
    --remaining;
    mGrid[position] = player;
    return false;
}

template<int mesh>
bool TicTacToe<mesh>::isFull() const
{
    return (remaining == 0) ? true : false;
}

template<int mesh>
bool TicTacToe<mesh>::isWinner(Player player) const
{
    // check for row or column wins
    std::array<bool, 2 * (mesh + 1)> win;
    win.fill(true);

    int j = 0;

    // checking condition loop
    std::for_each(mGrid.begin(), mGrid.end(),
        [&](Player i)
    {
        int x = j++;

        for (auto k = 0; k < mesh; ++k)
        {
            if (Match<mesh>(Type::column, k)(x))
                win[k] &= i == player;

            if (Match<mesh>(Type::row, k)(x))
                win[mesh + k] &= i == player;

            if (Match<mesh>(Type::diagonal, k)(x))
            {
                if (k < 2)
                    win[2 * mesh + k] &= i == player;
            }
        }
    });

    for (auto i : win)
    {
        if (i)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

template<int mesh>
void TicTacToe<mesh>::draw() const
{
    //Creating a onscreen grid
    std::cout << ' ';
    for (auto i = 1; i <= mesh; ++i)
        std::cout << "  " << i;

    int j = 0;
    char A = 'A';

    for (auto i : mGrid)
    {
        if (j == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\n " << A++;
            j = mesh;
        }
        --j;

        std::cout << ' ' << i << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

class Game
{
public:
    Game() = default;
    void run();

private:
    void showResult() const;
    void turn(int);

    static const unsigned mMesh = 3;
    TicTacToe<mMesh> mGame;
    std::array<Player, 2> mPlayers{ { Player::first, Player::second } };
    int mPlayer = 1;
};

void Game::run()
{
    std::cout   << "Please choose Game mod: \n"
                << " 1 - Player vs Player\n"
                << " 2 - player vs Computer\n\n> ";
    int choice;
    std::cin >> choice;

    while (!mGame.isWinner(mPlayers[mPlayer]) && !mGame.isFull())
    {
        mPlayer ^= 1;
        mGame.draw();
        turn(choice);
    }

    showResult();
}

void Game::showResult() const
{
    mGame.draw();

    if (mGame.isWinner(mPlayers[mPlayer]))
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << mPlayers[mPlayer] << " is the Winner!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nTie game!\n";
    }
}

void Game::turn(int n)
{
    char row = 0;
    char column = 0;
    if (n == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << mPlayers[mPlayer] << ": Please play. \n";

        for (bool pending = true; pending;)
        {
            std::cout << "Row(1,2,3,...): ";
            std::cin >> row;
            std::cout << mPlayers[mPlayer] << ": Column(A,B,C,...): ";
            std::cin >> column;

            column = std::toupper(column) - 'A';
            row -= '1';

            pending = column < 0 || row < 0 || mGame.applyMove(mPlayers[mPlayer], row, column);
            if (pending)
                std::cout << "Invalid position.  Try again.\n";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for (bool pending = true; pending;)
        {
            switch (mPlayers[mPlayer])
            {
            case Player::first:
                std::cout << "\n" << mPlayers[mPlayer] << ": Please play. \n";
                std::cout << "Row(1,2,3,...): ";
                std::cin >> row;
                std::cout << mPlayers[mPlayer] << ": Column(A,B,C,...): ";
                std::cin >> column;

                column = std::toupper(column) - 'A';
                row -= '1';

                pending = column < 0 || row < 0 || mGame.applyMove(mPlayers[mPlayer], row, column);
                if (pending)
                    std::cout << "Invalid position.  Try again.\n";
                break;
            case Player::second:
                row = getRandom(0, int(mMesh - 1));
                column = getRandom(0, int(mMesh - 1));
                pending = mGame.applyMove(mPlayers[mPlayer], row, column);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
    Game game;
    game.run();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll make a few suggestions on coding style and improvements:

- For `getRandom()`, you could be using the new [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library. `rand()` should be accurate enough for your purposes, but you can try the new library to also get more familiar with it. One small detail with `rand()` though. It is declared in the `<cstdlib>` header, so you should include it if you're using the function. Also, the proper way to reference it would be from the `std` namespace: `std::rand()`. Same goes for `std::srand()`.
- It would look neater to align the assignments in the enum constants:

  ```
  enum struct Player : char
  {
      none   = '-',
      first  = 'X',
      second = 'O'
  };
  ```
- Initializing enum constants with a 0,1,2 integer sequence is pointless, since the enum does exactly that if you don't initialize its constants:

  ```
  enum struct Type : int
  {
      row,
      column,
      diagonal
  };
  ```
- `template<int mesh>`: Template parameter names are usually written using `ALL_CAPS`. Most people also prefer them to be single letter names, like the famous `T` for a type. I would replace `mesh` with `MESH` to differentiate it from a variable name. YMMV, however, I don't find "mesh" to be the most adequate name here. This parameter is one of the board's dimensions, so it could be `SIZE` or `DIM`.
- You've made `TicTacToe` non-copyable and non-movable. It would also make sense deleting the assignment operator: `TicTacToe& operator = (const TicTacToe&) = delete;`
- The `for_each` in `TicTacToe::isWinner` could be replaced by a range based for loop, like you have used in several other places. That would make the code more uniform.

---

Overall, I think it is quite good and modern C++. You are on the right track.