# Tic-Tac-Toe in C++11 - follow-up 4

Tags: c++, game, c++11, random, tic-tac-toe

Previous question:

[Tic-Tac-Toe in C++11 - follow-up 3](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/71052/tic-tac-toe-in-c11-follow-up-3)

I've been told to use `<random>`. However, it seems a bit more complicated than it looks to generate random numbers. I have implemented it but I'm not quite sure whether I implemented it correctly or not.

What's the best practice for using `<random>` in this code particularly?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

enum struct Player : char
{
    none    = '-',
    first   = 'X',
    second  = 'O'
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Player p)
{
    return os << static_cast<char>(p);
}

enum struct Type : int
{
    row,
    column,
    diagonal
};

template<int DIM>
class TicTacToe
{
public:
    TicTacToe();
    TicTacToe(const TicTacToe &t) = delete;
    TicTacToe(const TicTacToe &&t) = delete;
    TicTacToe& operator = (const TicTacToe&) = delete;

    bool isFull() const;
    void draw() const;
    bool isWinner(Player player) const;
    bool applyMove(Player player, unsigned row, unsigned column);

private:
    unsigned remaining = DIM * DIM;
    std::array<Player, DIM * DIM> mGrid;
};

// utility functor to compute matching condition
template<int DIM>
struct Match
{
    Match(Type t, int i) : mCategory(t), mNumber(i){}
    bool operator() (int number) const
    {
        switch (mCategory)
        {
        case Type::row:
            return (std::abs(number / DIM) == mNumber);
        case Type::column:
            return (number % DIM == mNumber);
        case Type::diagonal:
            if (mNumber == 0)
                return ((std::abs(number / DIM) - number % DIM) == mNumber);
            if (mNumber == 1)
                return ((std::abs(number / DIM) + number % DIM) == mNumber + DIM - 2);
        default:
            return false;
        }
    }
    Type mCategory;
    int mNumber;
};

template<int DIM>
TicTacToe<DIM>::TicTacToe()
{
    mGrid.fill(Player::none);
}

template<int DIM>
bool TicTacToe<DIM>::applyMove(Player player, unsigned row, unsigned column)
{
    unsigned position = row + DIM * column;

    if ((position > mGrid.size()) || (mGrid[position] != Player::none))
        return true;

    --remaining;

    mGrid[position] = player;
    return false;
}

template<int DIM>
bool TicTacToe<DIM>::isFull() const
{
    return (remaining == 0) ? true : false;
}

template<int DIM>
bool TicTacToe<DIM>::isWinner(Player player) const
{
    std::array<bool, 2 * (DIM + 1)> win;
    win.fill(true);

    int j = 0;

    // checking condition loop
    for (auto i : mGrid)
    {
        int x = j++;

        for (auto k = 0; k < DIM; ++k)
        {
            if (Match<DIM>(Type::column, k)(x))
                win[k] &= i == player;

            if (Match<DIM>(Type::row, k)(x))
                win[DIM + k] &= i == player;

            if (Match<DIM>(Type::diagonal, k)(x))
            {
                if (k < 2)
                    win[2 * DIM + k] &= i == player;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto i : win)
    {
        if (i)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

template<int DIM>
void TicTacToe<DIM>::draw() const
{
    //Creating a onscreen grid
    std::cout << ' ';
    for (auto i = 1; i <= DIM; ++i)
        std::cout << "  " << i;

    int j = 0;
    char A = 'A';

    for (auto i : mGrid)
    {
        if (j == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\n " << A++;
            j = DIM;
        }
        --j;

        std::cout << ' ' << i << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

class Game
{
public:
    typedef std::default_random_engine Dre;
    Game() = default;
    void run(Dre);

private:
    void showResult() const;
    void turn(Dre);

    static const unsigned mDim = 3;
    TicTacToe<mDim> mGame;
    std::array<Player, 2> mPlayers{ { Player::first, Player::second } };
    int mPlayer = 1;
};

void Game::run(Dre e)
{
    while (!mGame.isWinner(mPlayers[mPlayer]) && !mGame.isFull())
    {
        mPlayer ^= 1;
        mGame.draw();
        turn(e);
    }

    showResult();
}

void Game::showResult() const
{
    mGame.draw();

    if (mGame.isWinner(mPlayers[mPlayer]))
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << mPlayers[mPlayer] << " is the Winner!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nTie game!\n";
    }
}

void Game::turn(Dre e1)
{
    char row = 0;
    char column = 0;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> uniform_dist(0, mDim - 1);
    auto getRandom = std::bind(uniform_dist, e1);

    for (bool pending = true; pending;)
    {
        switch (mPlayers[mPlayer])
        {
        case Player::first:
            std::cout << "\n" << mPlayers[mPlayer] << ": Please play. \n";
            std::cout << "Row(1,2,3,...): ";
            std::cin >> row;
            std::cout << mPlayers[mPlayer] << ": Column(A,B,C,...): ";
            std::cin >> column;

            column = std::toupper(column) - 'A';
            row -= '1';

            pending = column < 0 || row < 0 || mGame.applyMove(mPlayers[mPlayer], row, column);
            if (pending)
                std::cout << "Invalid position.  Try again.\n";
            break;
        case Player::second:
            row = getRandom();
            column = getRandom();
            pending = mGame.applyMove(mPlayers[mPlayer], row, column);
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine e(rd());
    Game game;
    game.run(e);
}
```

Comment: This is a nice talk about `rand` and the new `<random>` library: http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful

Comment: Instead of `foo == x ? true : false` you can just use `foo == x`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this approach is better. I have created a `struct` called `Random` to initialize related `random` structs and data types:

```
// utility class for Random Number Generation
struct Random
{
    Random(int min, int max)
        : mUniformDistribution(min, max)
    {}

    int operator()()
    {
        return mUniformDistribution(mEngine);
    }

    std::default_random_engine mEngine{ std::random_device()() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> mUniformDistribution;
};
```

Complete code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <ctime>

struct Mute
{
    Mute() = default;
    Mute(const Mute &) = delete;
    Mute(const Mute &&) = delete;
    Mute& operator = (const Mute&) = delete;
};

enum struct Player : char
{
    none    = '-',
    first   = 'X',
    second  = 'O'
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Player p)
{
    return os << static_cast<char>(p);
}

enum struct Type : int
{
    row,
    column,
    diagonal
};

template<std::size_t DIM>
class TicTacToe : public Mute
{
public:
    TicTacToe();

    bool isFull() const;
    void draw() const;
    bool isWinner(Player player) const;
    bool applyMove(Player player, std::size_t row, std::size_t column);

private:
    std::size_t mRemain = DIM * DIM;
    std::array<Player, DIM * DIM> mGrid;
};

template<int DIM>
struct Match : public Mute
{
    Match(Type t, int i) 
        : mCategory(t)
        , mNumber(i)
    {}

    bool operator() (int number) const
    {
        switch (mCategory)
        {
        case Type::row:
            return (std::abs(number / DIM) == mNumber);

        case Type::column:
            return (number % DIM == mNumber);

        case Type::diagonal:
            if (mNumber == 0)
                return ((std::abs(number / DIM) - number % DIM) == mNumber);
            if (mNumber == 1)
                return ((std::abs(number / DIM) + number % DIM) == mNumber + DIM - 2);

        default:
            return false;
        }
    }

    Type mCategory;
    int mNumber;
};

template<std::size_t DIM>
TicTacToe<DIM>::TicTacToe()
{
    mGrid.fill(Player::none);
}

template<std::size_t DIM>
bool TicTacToe<DIM>::applyMove(Player player, std::size_t row, std::size_t column)
{
    std::size_t position = row + DIM * column;

    if ((position > mGrid.size()) || (mGrid[position] != Player::none))
        return true;

    --mRemain;

    mGrid[position] = player;
    return false;
}

template<std::size_t DIM>
bool TicTacToe<DIM>::isFull() const
{
    return (mRemain == 0);
}

template<std::size_t DIM>
bool TicTacToe<DIM>::isWinner(Player player) const
{
    std::array<bool, 2 * (DIM + 1)> win;
    win.fill(true);

    int j = 0;

    for (auto i : mGrid)
    {
        int x = j++;

        for (auto k = 0; k < DIM; ++k)
        {
            if (Match<DIM>(Type::column, k)(x))
                win[k] &= i == player;

            if (Match<DIM>(Type::row, k)(x))
                win[DIM + k] &= i == player;

            if (Match<DIM>(Type::diagonal, k)(x))
            {
                if (k < 2)
                    win[2 * DIM + k] &= i == player;
            }
        }
    }

    for (auto i : win)
    {
        if (i)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

template<std::size_t DIM>
void TicTacToe<DIM>::draw() const
{
    std::cout << ' ';
    for (auto i = 1; i <= DIM; ++i)
        std::cout << "  " << i;

    int j = 0;
    char A = 'A';

    for (auto i : mGrid)
    {
        if (j == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "\n " << A++;
            j = DIM;
        }
        --j;

        std::cout << ' ' << i << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

struct Random : public Mute
{
    Random(int min, int max)
        : mUniformDistribution(min, max)
    {}

    int operator()()
    {
        return mUniformDistribution(mEngine);
    }

    std::default_random_engine mEngine{ std::random_device()() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> mUniformDistribution;
};

class Game : public Mute
{
public:
    void run();

private:
    void showResult() const;
    void turn();

    static const std::size_t mDim = 3;
    TicTacToe<mDim> mGame;
    std::array<Player, 2> mPlayers{ { Player::first, Player::second } };
    int mPlayer = 1;
    Random getRandom{ 0, mDim - 1 };
};

void Game::run()
{
    while (!mGame.isWinner(mPlayers[mPlayer]) && !mGame.isFull())
    {
        mPlayer ^= 1;
        mGame.draw();
        turn();
    }

    showResult();
}

void Game::showResult() const
{
    mGame.draw();

    if (mGame.isWinner(mPlayers[mPlayer]))
    {
        std::cout << "\n" << mPlayers[mPlayer] << " is the Winner!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "\nTie game!\n";
    }
}

void Game::turn()
{
    char row = 0;
    char column = 0;

    for (bool pending = true; pending;)
    {
        switch (mPlayers[mPlayer])
        {
        case Player::first:
            std::cout << "\n" << mPlayers[mPlayer] << ": Please play. \n";
            std::cout << "Row(1,2,3,...): ";
            std::cin >> row;
            std::cout << mPlayers[mPlayer] << ": Column(a,b,c,...): ";
            std::cin >> column;

            column = std::toupper(column) - 'A';
            row -= '1';

            pending = column < 0 || row < 0 || mGame.applyMove(mPlayers[mPlayer], row, column);
            if (pending)
                std::cout << "Invalid position.  Try again.\n";
            break;
        case Player::second:
            row = getRandom();
            column = getRandom();

            pending = mGame.applyMove(mPlayers[mPlayer], row, column);
            break;
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.run();
}
```